# Wicket Atmosphere jQuery noConflict

Tags: jquery, wicket, atmosphere

Our application uses jQuery.noConflict changing all references from $ to $j. We are trying to integrate Wicket Atmosphere into our application, however, are running into an issue where it is rendering a $ in an OnDomReadyHeaderItem.forScript. This is of course causing javascript errors.

We have tracked it down to the renderHead method of AtmosphereBehavior. The $ is hard coded in the javascript string.

Does anyone know if it is possible to extend AtmosphereBehavior and have Wicket Atmosphere use our custom version?

Or it is possible to extend OnDomReadyHeaderItem which we would do a replace on $( with $j( and have wicket use that globally?

Any thoughts on how to resolve this issue? Using Wicket Atmosphere .18 and Wicket 6.11 currently.

Thanks, 
Matt

Answer (score 1):

I have answered you at Wicket's mailing lists: http://markmail.org/message/y6sgtnui7wly2f7w

Comment: Yes, you are awesome for that. Posted in both places! Thanks again.